# How to replace text in a string without a selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to take something like

```
var value = 'Hello there';
```

and do a jQuery replace, like

```
$(value).replace('there','world');
```

Every example I can find will show you how to replace text that is in an HTML object, what if it's just in JS?

-   -

Is there a way to do this with jquery?
use the $ selector to select a variable?

Comment: What do you mean by "a jQuery replace"? Why are you doing something in jQuery that can be handled perfectly well in vanilla JS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
value = value.replace('there','world');
```

If you want to replace every occurrence, you must use a regex with the `g` flag (even if it's just a normal string you want to replace):

```
value = value.replace( /there/g, 'world' );
```

Comment: What about replacing a '"' with regex? /g

Comment: @KirkStrobek You're asking how to replace every occurrence of a double-quote character with something else? `result = mystr.replace( /"/g, "..." );`